# Export data from SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 on the network server and 'central' DB. To workaround cases when the network is down I decided to implement 'local' design on all clients. Actually I have 5 clients. I installed SQL Server 2014 Express on each client and created exact as 'central' empty database on each client.

Now during network outage I'm able to continue collect data and populate it in each of 5 databases.

When the network is up again I have to copy/move collected data from each client to the 'central' db. Unfortunately the 'central' and 'local' databases are on a different network and can't see each other hence I have to somehow export package from each 'local' db and then import it into 'central'.

The problem that I hit is that in SQL Server Express there's not an option to save package i.e. it allow only immediate export which would not work for me.

Do you have an idea how to handle this situation?

Thanks

Comment: @Rahul: that's **not** going to work from SQL Server **2014** Express "down" to SQL Server **2008** .....

Comment: All set, Thanks for info. I installed client 2008 R2 and now it's working. Ticket could be closed